# core-list-dart template how to bind to the model itself

Tags: data-binding, dart, dart-polymer, core-elements

I'm using the `<core-list-dart>` element in my Polymer Dart application:

```dart
<core-list-dart data="{{data}}">
  <template>
        <span>{{name}}</span>
  </template>
</core-list-dart>
```

Data is an array of Foo where Foo is:

```dart
class Foo {
  String name;
  ...
}
```

It is possible in the template refer to the Foo instance instead of his fields?

Something like:

```dart
<core-list-dart data="{{data}}">
  <template>
        <foo-element foo="{{ITEM}}"></foo-element>
  </template>
</core-list-dart>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From version **0.4.0** of core_elements the model is exposed as `model` variable in the template.

**Old response**:

To bind the Item you can use the `{{}}` annotation as explained in the @Günter Zöchbauer answer:

```dart
<foo-element foo="{{}}"></foo-element>
```

The problem is that the elements in the array are wrapped by a ListModel class. The "real" element is not accessible (maybe the library can be modified giving this possibility).

The workaround is to put a getter to the model object (Foo) like this:

```dart
class Foo {
 String name;
 Foo get self => this;
 ...
}
```

So in the template you can do this:

```dart
<foo-element foo="{{self}}"></foo-element>
```

Comment: I tried it again and I also can't see another solution for this currently. I create the issue https://github.com/dart-lang/core-elements/issues/112.

Comment: I just hit the same thing. Very annoying. Thanks for providing the workaround. Not pretty but hopefully does the trick

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it and it works.

```dart
<foo-element foo="{{}}"></foo-element>
```

see https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/polymer_expressions - Repeating templates

Comment: I've tried and I'm getting a: Exception: type '_ListModel' is not a subtype of type 'Foo' of 'value'. As I can see from https://github.com/dart-lang/core-elements/blob/master/lib/core_list_dart.dart the elements in the array are wrapped in a ListModel class.

Comment: Ok, i just tried if 'something' is assigned. I'll take a closer look.

Comment: The related issue to expose the data item inside the template is fixed in JS https://github.com/dart-lang/core-elements/issues/112
Hopefully this will land in the Dart core-elements with the next update.