# core-list-dart bind selection to property

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, core-elements

It is possible to bind the item selected in the [core-list-dart](http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/core_elements/0.3.0+1/index.html#core_elements/core_elements-core_list_dart.CoreList) element to a variable?

Something like:

```
 <core-list-dart data={{data}} height="80" selected={{selected}}>
```

Where data is my `List<Item>` and selected is an `Item`.

Comment: What value is assinged to `selected`? Isn't this the selected item?

Comment: The value of selected remains null.

Comment: Related issue https://github.com/dart-lang/core-elements/issues/121

Comment: You shouldn't change the someone elses answer so that the meaning changes notable, create a new answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `core-activate` event passes the selected item.

```dart
void activateHandler(dom.CustomEvent e) {
  print(e.detail.data);
}
```

```dart
 <core-list-dart data={{data}} height="80" on-core-activate="{{activateHandler}}">
```

The `core-list` doesn't provide a `selected` attribute but the item in the template does.

```dart
<core-list-dart data="{{data}}"  on-core-activate="{{activateHandler}}">
  <template>
      <div>{{name}} - selected: {{selected}}</div>
  </template>
</core-list-dart>
```

I used your `Foo` class as example from your other question [core-list-dart template how to bind to the model itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930606)

Comment: There is a selected property, but with no documentation: http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/core_elements/0.3.0+1/index.html#core_elements/core_elements-core_list_dart.CoreList@id_selected

Comment: I have seen it in the code but it doesn't seem to get updated and the Polymer.js core-list doesn't have it at all.

Answer (score 0):

The `selected` property in `core-list-dart` is not documented https://github.com/dart-lang/core-elements/issues/121.

As I can understand from the code the property is observed for changes and the selection should be updated consequently, but it does not work.

The only solution is to listen to selection changes through the `core-activate` event as proposed by Günter Zöchbauer.

The event `details.data` property contains the selected item.

Comment: I think this observable `selected` field is there by mistake because the Polymer.js element doesn't have it. But I assume the response to the issue you created will tell...

Comment: I'm not so sure is there by mistake because the field is "observed" and used here: https://github.com/dart-lang/core-elements/blob/master/lib/core_list_dart.dart#L361